# Oracle 10g Error: Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have created database where I want autoincrement the primary key. I tried to trigger it but getting the above error
here is my description of table:

```
SQL> desc users
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USER_ID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 FIRST_NAME                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 LAST_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 CITY                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 COUNTRY                                            VARCHAR2(20)
 PASSWORD                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(16)
 EMAIL_ID                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
```

when I  am trying to trigger it getting the error:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE SYSTEM.MYSEQ
 2  START WITH 1
 3  MAXVALUE 99999999
 4  MINVALUE 1
 5  NOCYCLE
 6  CACHE 20
 7  NOORDER;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_USERS BEFORE INSERT ON USERS FOR EACH ROW
2  BEGIN SELECT LPAD(LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(MYSEQ.NEXTVAL))),10,'0') INTO :NEW.USER_ID FROM DUAL;
3  /
```

please help me to solve this error.

Comment: The title (and code) seems to reference Oracle, yet you tagged your question MySql?

Comment: Please execute `show errors` to display a list of errors and add these errors to the question One thing I immediately notice: you have a `BEGIN` but no `END`

Comment: 10 g is oracle have amended the tags

Comment: Version 10g is *very* old. Even support ended many years ago. *Must* you work with such an old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error, because you are missing the trigger's `END`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_USERS
  BEFORE INSERT ON USERS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT LPAD(LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(MYSEQ.NEXTVAL))),10,'0')
    INTO :NEW.USER_ID 
  FROM DUAL;
END; -- <=== this one
/
```

The trigger doesn't seem to make much sense, by the way. `LPAD(LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(MYSEQ.NEXTVAL))),10,'0')` is just an obfuscated `TO_CHAR(MYSEQ.NEXTVAL, 'FM0000000000')`, but then, why create a string with leading zeros, when `USERS.USER_ID` is numeric??? You turn 123 into '0000000123' only to store it as 123.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the trigger, as far as *compilation* is concerned (apart from the fact that you "forgot" to `END` it).

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_USERS
  2    BEFORE INSERT ON USERS
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT lpad(ltrim(rtrim(to_char(myseq.nextval))), 10, '0')
  6    INTO :new.user_id
  7    FROM dual;
  8  END;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> INSERT INTO USERS (FIRST_NAME) VALUES ('Little');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM users;

   USER_ID FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAE   CITY       COUNTRY    PASSW EMAIL_ID
---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------------------
         1 Little

SQL>
```

---

However, if `USER_ID` is `NUMBER`, you're overcomplicated trigger code because whatever you do with those functions, you'll - at the end - get just a **number**. As you can see from my example, `USER_ID = 1`.

If it were `VARCHAR2`, then

```
SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE users;

Table truncated.

SQL> ALTER TABLE USERS MODIFY user_id VARCHAR2(10);

Table altered.

SQL> INSERT INTO USERS (FIRST_NAME) VALUES ('Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM users;

USER_ID    FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAE   CITY       COUNTRY    PASSW EMAIL_ID
---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------------------
0000000002 Foot

SQL>
```

See the difference?

---

Trigger could've been simpler (but not *much* simpler; you're on 10g, after all) as there's nothing to *trim*:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_USERS
  2    BEFORE INSERT ON USERS
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT lpad(to_char(myseq.nextval), 10, '0')
  6    INTO :new.user_id
  7    FROM dual;
  8  END;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> INSERT INTO USERS (FIRST_NAME) VALUES ('Krishna');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM users;

USER_ID    FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAE   CITY       COUNTRY    PASSW EMAIL_ID
---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------------------
0000000002 Foot
0000000003 Krishna

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing `end` keyword, you don't need all the character formatting or the 'select from dual'. I would just use:

```
create or replace trigger tr_users
    before insert on users
    for each row
begin
    :new.user_id := myseq.nextval; 
end;
```

By the way, your sequence can also be written more simply as:

```
create sequence myseq;
```

Also, there is no need to code in uppercase. It's a bad habit from the 1970s.